# Selecting Elements whilst using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi Everyone (this is my first question here at Stack Overflow)...

I have been looking into using JSoup to create a small program. What I am looking to do is select a specific piece of data to print out. For example I have this code:

```
<div id="olpDivId">
<span class="olpCondLink">
    <a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/0747574480/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new">26&nbsp;new</a> &nbsp;from&nbsp;
    <span class="price">£2.88</span>
</span>
<span class="olpCondLink">
    <a class="buyAction olpBlueLink" href="/gp/offer-listing/0747574480/ref=dp_olp_used?ie=UTF8&condition=used">14&nbsp;used</a>&nbsp;from&nbsp;
    <span class="price">£0.01</span>
</span>
</div>
```

I am looking to only get the two span class="price" pieces of data However the page also  has other pieces of data with the same span class. I am wondering if it would be possible to only show the elements with span class price, that are also a member of span class="olpCondLink" or div id="olpDivId" as the other HTML doesn't share the same ID.

I currently have the following code in Java:

```
Elements links = doc.select("div[id=olpDivId] > span[class=price]");
```

But it isn't returning anything...

Any help is greatly appreciated, and I hope my question made sense.
Regards,
Jamie.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (1.6.2), this should work.

```
Elements prices = doc.select("span.price");
```

Look at the [syntax](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).

Answer (score -1):

you can find some more details in the below link,"http://javadomain.in/how-to-count-the-number-of-div-using-jsoup/"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Answers should be complete answers, including relevant code snippets and an explanation. Answers that are just links are not nearly as useful.